# Publish Web Deploy Doesn't Delete Files with VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, azure, publish

Publishing my local site to an Azure profile with web deploy method.  If I delete a file and publish, the file remains on the server.  I've seen similar versions of this question with answers suggesting either to check the 'delete all files when publishing' (not an option in VS 2017) or to delete bin and obj folders and re-publish (tried several times).

Any other suggestions on getting files to sync when publishing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could right-click your project -> publish, then follow the screenshots below to check the option **Remove additional files at destination**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks - not sure how I missed that

Comment: Thanks for this. I had removed a CSS file from my project and it was still being served from the server.