# An edited page is not being published when publishing website in azure

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

I am trying to publish my project using **visual studio** into **azure** but a page in which i changed the code is not being published it is not even shown in the preview section when trying to publish. why is it so? can someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

I think you could check the file in your project via the [Kudu Console](https://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/How-to-add-edit-and-remove-files-in-your-azure-webapp-using-the-kudu-service-dashboard/), if the file was changed or not.

Or try to choose the `Remove additional files at destination` option when you pubishing the project, refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279521/publish-web-deploy-doesnt-delete-files-with-vs-2017/50283627#50283627), it will be fine.